# Push Function React Native Return Object And Undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I got a strange push object in here

```
[
  [
    {
      "buyerVolume": "617,742",
      "buyerVolumePercent": "71.42857",
      "chart": "c1",
      "code": 200,
      "company": "Bank Central Asia Tbk.",
      "date": "3/10/2022",
      "id": 1,
      "link": "https://blablabla.id",
      "ma200": "7,011",
      "ma60": "7,674",
      "message": "Pull Data Successfuly",
      "pivotHighLow": undefined,
      "resistance": "8,225",
      "sellerVolume": "247,097",
      "sellerVolumePercent": undefined,
      "status": "Success",
      "support": "7,650",
      "takingProfit": "8,350",
      "ticker": "BBCA",
      "trailStop": "7,750",
      "value": "683,223,600,000",
    },
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
  ],
]
```

I got so many **undefined**

**This is how I push the data :**

```
let modelData = new ApiChartingDataModel();
    let data = [];    
                          
    modelData = new ApiChartingDataModel ({
            id: 1,
            code: response.data.Code,
            status: response.data.Status,
            message: response.data.Message,
            link: response.data.Data.Link,
            chart: response.data.Data.Chart,
            company: response.data.Data.Company,
            date: response.data.Data.Date,
            ticker: response.data.Data.Ticker,
            value: response.data.Data.Value,
            sellerVolume: response.data.Data.SellerVolume,
            sellerVolumePercent: response.data.Data.SellerVolumePercent,
            buyerVolume: response.data.Data.BuyerVolume,
            buyerVolumePercent: response.data.Data.BuyerVolumePercent,
            ma60: response.data.Data.MA60,
            ma200: response.data.Data.MA200,
            resistance: response.data.Data.Resistance,
            support: response.data.Data.Support,
            pivotHighLow: response.data.Data.PivotHighLow,
            takingProfit: response.data.Data.TakingProfit,
            trailStop: response.data.Data.TrailStop
    });                            

    
    data.push(Object.values(modelData).flat());
```

when console.log(data), I got so many undefined. I just push one model structure and didn't do looping, but I got undefined.

Why it is appear right that ? and how to solve it ?

**Edit**

[image]

**Second Edit**

This is my Model Data

```
class ApiChartingDataModel {
  constructor(id, code, status, message, link, chart, company, date, ticker, value, sellerVolume, sellerVolumePercent, buyerVolume, buyerVolumePercent, ma60, ma200, resistence, support, pivotHightLow, takingProfit, trailStop) {
    this.id = id;
    this.code = code;
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
    this.link = link;
    this.chart = chart;
    this.company = company;
    this.date = date;
    this.ticker = ticker;
    this.value = value;
    this.sellerVolume = sellerVolume;
    this.sellerVolumePercent = sellerVolumePercent;
    this.buyerVolume = buyerVolume;
    this.buyerVolumePercent = buyerVolumePercent;
    this.ma60 = ma60;
    this.ma200 = ma200;
    this.resistence = resistence;
    this.support = support;
    this.pivotHightLow = pivotHightLow;
    this.takingProfit = takingProfit;
    this.trailStop = trailStop;

  }
}

export default ApiChartingDataModel;
```

Comment: The keys in your object all start with lower case letter, e.g. `code`, but you access them in your code with capital letter, e.g. `Code`?

Comment: that doesnt seem the problem. I have change it and the result is same

Comment: Could you log `response.data` and post the result?

Comment: @DavidScholz I have update the question and post the response.data.

Comment: Ooh, it looks like you have an array in an array and in that array is your object. Does `response.data[0][0]?.code` work?

Comment: so what is the proper way fix it ?

Comment: Did it work, or didn't it? (`response.data[0][0]?.code`)

Comment: it work and print out the variable code

Comment: Well, then that is the solution. You have an object inside an array inside an array.  It now depends on your data. Will there be more arrays? If not, you could flatten your array first.

Comment: is it possible to remove array and just have and object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive an array which contains an array and inside of it, there is your object, thus the following code allows you to access it.

```js
// accessing the object with no guards against empty arrays or undefined
const obj = response.data[0][0]
console.log(obj.code)
```

It now depends on your data. If you know that there will be always one array inside an array and all objects will be inside of it (or there will always be a single object), then we could make this easier as follows.

**Multiple objects inside nested array**

```js
const dummyData = [
  [
    {
      "buyerVolume": "617,742",
      "buyerVolumePercent": "71.42857",
      "chart": "c1",
      "code": 200,
      "company": "Bank Central Asia Tbk.",
      "date": "3/10/2022",
      "id": 1,
      "link": "https://blablabla.id",
      "ma200": "7,011",
      "ma60": "7,674",
      "message": "Pull Data Successfuly",
      "pivotHighLow": undefined,
      "resistance": "8,225",
      "sellerVolume": "247,097",
      "sellerVolumePercent": undefined,
      "status": "Success",
      "support": "7,650",
      "takingProfit": "8,350",
      "ticker": "BBCA",
      "trailStop": "7,750",
      "value": "683,223,600,000",
    },
    {
      "buyerVolume": "617,742",
      "buyerVolumePercent": "71.42857",
      "chart": "c1",
      "code": 200,
      "company": "Bank Central Asia Tbk.",
      "date": "3/10/2022",
      "id": 1,
      "link": "https://blablabla.id",
      "ma200": "7,011",
      "ma60": "7,674",
      "message": "Pull Data Successfuly",
      "pivotHighLow": undefined,
      "resistance": "8,225",
      "sellerVolume": "247,097",
      "sellerVolumePercent": undefined,
      "status": "Success",
      "support": "7,650",
      "takingProfit": "8,350",
      "ticker": "BBCA",
      "trailStop": "7,750",
      "value": "683,223,600,000",
    },
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
  ],
]

const data = dummyData.flat().filter(a => a)
console.log(data)
```

The above filters all `undefined` objects inside the nested array and flattens the parent array resulting in an array of objects.

**You know that you will always have one object**

```js
const dummyData = [
  [
    {
      "buyerVolume": "617,742",
      "buyerVolumePercent": "71.42857",
      "chart": "c1",
      "code": 200,
      "company": "Bank Central Asia Tbk.",
      "date": "3/10/2022",
      "id": 1,
      "link": "https://blablabla.id",
      "ma200": "7,011",
      "ma60": "7,674",
      "message": "Pull Data Successfuly",
      "pivotHighLow": undefined,
      "resistance": "8,225",
      "sellerVolume": "247,097",
      "sellerVolumePercent": undefined,
      "status": "Success",
      "support": "7,650",
      "takingProfit": "8,350",
      "ticker": "BBCA",
      "trailStop": "7,750",
      "value": "683,223,600,000",
    },
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
  ],
]

const data = dummyData.flat().filter(a => a).pop()
console.log(data)
```